# Space between arrow and title in a titled pane

Tags: css, javafx

I have created a titled pane. I want to have a wider space between the arrow (in the example the "person" icon) and the title.
[image: TitledPane]

I have tried using CSS

```
.titled-pane > .title {
-fx-padding: 10 10 10 10;
```

or

```
-fx-background-insets: 10 10 10 10;
```

But nothing seems to move the items. 
How can I do this?

Comment: @Marvin this is a [JavaFX question](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-overview.htm), there is no html to include.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```css
.titled-pane > .title > .arrow-button {
    -fx-padding: 0.0em 1.66em 0em 0em ;
}
```

(The default padding on the right is 0.583em, which is 7px in the default windows settings.)

Comment: It worked, I changed  `.titled-pane > .title { 
-fx-padding:` along wit your suggestion and was able to do it.
Thanks!